# Minimalistic page.tpl.php file

Tags: 7, theming

Do you know what to write to the **page.tpl.php** file so that it shows only 5 regions (header, menu, left_sidebar, content, right_sidebar)?
Something like the following code, but to work correctly with other Drupal files and components (like *.info file) and don't collide with Drupal default regions.

```
<body>
  <div id="header"><?php print $page['header']; ?></div>
  <div id="menu"><?php print $page['menu']; ?></div>
  <div id="left"><?php print $page['left']; ?></div>
  <div id="content"><?php print $page['content']; ?></div>
  <div id="right"><?php print $page['right']; ?></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/render/7) like this:

```
 <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

I'm not really sure what you mean by "but to work correctly with other Drupal files and components."

You should also print all the standard regions and any other variables you might need. You can find a list of the default variables available to page.tpl.php in the [documentation page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php/7).

Also here's a list of the regions you probably should include:

- `$page['help']`: Dynamic help text, mostly for admin pages.
- `$page['highlighted']`: Items for the highlighted content region.
- `$page['content']`: The main content of the current page.
- `$page['sidebar_first']`: Items for the first sidebar.
- `$page['sidebar_second']`: Items for the second sidebar.
- `$page['header']`: Items for the header region.
- `$page['footer']`: Items for the footer region.

Comment: OK, I repaired it according to your advice. In firebug I can see my regions, but they are empty (e.g. `<div id="left"></div>` or `<div id="right">Array</div>`). In Structure -> Blocks I assigned to the regions some blocks (RSS, login) but they aren't rendered.

Comment: You need to use print render() for every variable.

Comment: I used print render(). It corrected it as follows : `<div id="right"></div>`. But I have a navigation and login in left region and RSS in right region and it's still empty.

Comment: Are you using $page['sidebar_first'] and $page['sidebar_second']? in drupal-7 there is no longer $left and $right variables.

Comment: I'm using `<div id="left"><?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?></div>` and `<div id="right"><?php print render($page['sidebar_second']); ?></div>` In tmp.info there are lines `regions[sidebar_first] = "Left region"` and `regions[sidebar_second] = "Right region"`

Comment: In block demonstration I can see the regions.

Comment: That's strange but the following reparation helped. 1) rename in **.tmp** file `regions[sidebar_first] = "Sidebar first"` and `regions[sidebar_second] = "Sidebar second"` 2) rename CCS ID's in **page.tpl.php** and **style.css** to `sidebar-first` and `sidebar-second` (note the dashes).